# When I submit register, the controller is taking to Http Get instead of HttpPost

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the controller code

```
public class ConsultantRegisterController : Controller
{
    // GET: ConsultantRegister
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            return View(db.Consultant.ToList());
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(Consultant accnt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                db.Consultant.Add(accnt);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            accnt = null;
            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Consultant user)
    {
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            var usr = db.Consultant.Single(u => u.UserId == user.UserId && u.Password == user.Password);
            if(usr!= null)
            {
                Session["ConsultantID"] = usr.ConsultantId.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = usr.UserId.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is Wrong");
            }
        }
            return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoggedIn()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the registration form

```
@model MvcWebForms.Models.Consultant
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Consultant</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">@ViewBag.Message</div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" >Register</button>
                @*<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" />*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

I am trying for the whole day but unable to figure it out where am doing wrong. Whenever I try to register it is getting back to [Http GET], but in order to save it should go to [http post].

Answer (score 0):

@thoutam srikar

you should use

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Action name", "Controller name", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Tried that too, but no use, still going to httpGet after submission

Comment: @thoutamsrikar After adding the configuration that Manish suggested, watch the network traffic in your browser's development tools. Does it POST to the correct URL?

Comment: @mason sorry mason am not aware of development tools

Comment: @thoutam Hit F12 in your browser to bring up the development tools.

Comment: @thoutam is it a POST or GET when you view it in the dev tools?

Comment: @mason for browser link the requested method is GET

Comment: @mason Request URL:http://localhost:50481/1c13e11a1b7649f69706bfaa118bd03a/browserLink
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:50481
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: @thoutamsrikar No, not browser link. We don't care about that. Look at the actual request that's going to your controller, the one with the correct URL.

Comment: @mason here non of the URL is Post, everything is GET

Comment: Okay, did you follow Manish's directions? Do you have more than one form on the page? And we don't care whether the other URL's are GET or POST, we only care about the request that runs when you submit the form.

Comment: I don't have more than one form on this page, and yes I followed Manish's directions, still the result is same

Comment: @thoutam srikar first thing you will describe your form is submitted or not

Comment: After adding                                                                                       
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action name", "Controller name", FormMethod.Post))                                                                                                                 its working fine i test it